# Cryptomatte has gaps between them

Tags: mesh, compositing-nodes, cryptomatte

So when i composited my render, i noticed my cryptomatte somehow have some gaps that cause glitches

[image]

the soldier and the wood has noticeable gaps
and after i checked the cryptomatte data, it does have some gaps

Comment: Is depth of field turned on?

Comment: Aha, it looks like the motion blur’s causing the trouble. Hmm, don’t know much about cryptomatte myself, but I prefer view layers.